how to write a theme.of(context).colorscheme.primary for logo
I have writen an light mode code with flutter and i added a color code is primary: Colors.grey.shade500,
but when i write a color for a logo it displays under Theme. Of(context) an error but the rest no have an error full code Theme. Of(context).ColorScheme.primary,
I tried to add an import for each page

Welcome to Stack Overflow. To help, we need to see a minimal reproducible example of your code, not just an explanation. Please edit your question to include enough code (as text, not as images) for us to reproduce the problem.

Without code, it's very hard to help you.

To use Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary for a logo or any widget, you need to ensure that:
The ThemeData is correctly set up in your MaterialApp or Theme widget.
The widget where you're using Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary has access to the BuildContext that is within the scope of the MaterialApp or Theme widget.
Define the Theme in MaterialApp
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
          seedColor: Colors.grey.shade500,
        ),
      ),
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

Use colorScheme.primary for Your Logo
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Icon(
          Icons.ac_unit, // Example logo
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
          size: 100, // Size of the logo
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

